# ¿C# ASP.NET como generar token para autenticar con Google?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Explico que es lo que necesito hacer y pido si alguno me puede dar una idea de por donde ir ya que por mas que leo no encuentro la solución.

Yo tengo una aplicación ya hecha con WebForms. Necesito hacer que esta aplicación reciba un usuario y contraseña desde un servidor RADIUS, verifique que ese usuario y contraseña sean validos en Google Accounts, realice otras verificaciones internas (verificar si el usuario tiene autorizada la salida a internet) y devuelva true o false al servidor RADIUS.

El problema es que no se cómo hacer para validar contra google. Según leí tengo que generar un token con los datos del usuario y enviarlo a google, pero no se como hacerlo. Cualquier ayuda sobre esto será bienvenida.

Comment: El usuario te de su usuario y password de google para que vos se lo pases a google??? OMG.. suena muy muy raro...

Comment: `Necesito hacer que esta aplicación reciba un usuario y contraseña desde un servidor RADIUS, verifique que ese usuario y contraseña sean validos en Google Accounts` ¿En qué momento planeas mostrar el proceso de autenticación de Google? ¿Has revisado cómo funciona en la documentación oficial?

Comment: TAl vez nos estemos perdiendo algo. Pero por la documentacion de google (que si, es mucha y a veces confusa), vos le preguntas a google quien es el usuario logueado, y google te contesta con sus datos. En un proceso de varias capas. tal vez, no estamos entendiendo algo en este caso?

Answer (score 0):

Para una doble atuenticacion usando Radios debes configurar ese servidor
de manera que.

http://gradew.net/2015/01/05/googleauthfreeradius/

Otra es usando una autenticacion externa usando google y obtener un token e informacion basica autorizada por el usuario.

Para este caso se creao una cuenta de Cliente desarrollador en google
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Developer-Console-Generate-Client-ID-and-Client-Secret-for-use-with-Google-APIs.aspx

Despues solo agregas la autorizacion en .Net usando terceras aplicaciones
en la red hay bastantes articulos al respecto. Lo importante a modificar es cuando tengas el Callback de tu login externo solo obtienes email y lo debes comparar con radius, aqui agregas la validacion con radious,
para validacion con radios solo tendras el email de usuario, sin contrasena asi que tendras que buscar la manera de que radios solo te verfique que es un usuario activo.

Intenta implementarlos y agrega el codigo para ir resolviendo tus dudas mas especificamente.

Comment: Intento explicar mejor el proceso. 
Un usuario se intenta conectar a un servidor Radius, este envía la información (usuario y contraseña) a mi aplicación, esta pregunta a Google si ese usuario y contraseña son validos (no me interesa obtener otra información, son usuarios gestionados por mi empresa osea que yo ya tengo la información necesaria, yo quiero saber si la contraseña es correcta en google nada más), Google me responde si el usuario y contraseña son validos y correctos, mi aplicación hace otras cosas y le responde al Servidor Radius si es correcto o no el login.

Comment: edite la respuesta para indicarte los pasos de tu implementacion